# BindingContext Unknown Resolve Error MVVMCross

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a view

```
public class TestView : MvxActionBarActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TestView);

            var responsesList = this.FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
            var responsesAdapter = new TestViewAdapter(this, (IMvxAndroidBindingContext) BindingContext );
            responsesList.Adapter = responsesAdapter;



            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<TestView, TestViewModel>();
            set.Bind(responsesAdapter).For(s => s.Responses).To(vm => vm.Responses);
            set.Bind(responsesList).For(x => x.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Responses);
            set.Bind(responsesList).For(x => x.ItemClick).To(vm => vm.ShowDetailEntry);


            set.Apply();
        }
}
```

For some reason the above code says unknown resolve error on binding context. I can't figure out why and there is a ton of lacking tutorials on Xamaring MVVM Cross. What am I missin for:

`var responsesAdapter = new TestViewAdapter(this, (IMvxAndroidBindingContext) BindingContext );`

[image]
Adapter Code:

```
public class TestViewAdapter : MvxAdapter
{
        public TestAdapter(Context context, IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext)
            : base(context, bindingContext)
          {
          }

          public List<TestResponse> Responses { get; set; }

          protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object source, int templateId)
             {
                if (Session.CurrentArea == 2)
                {
                    templateId = Resource.Layout.quickview_row;
                }
                return base.GetBindableView(convertView, source, templateId);
             }
}
```

Comment: can you add the error description.

Comment: Add TestViewAdapter class code.

Comment: I added both now Nikita

Comment: You have name conflicts??TestAdapter  & TestViewAdapter

Comment: no sorry its from retyping in here...i copied and pasted but the formatting was off and accidentally must have fat fingered something

Comment: I feel its more like a classname then a property. try to go to the defination & check.

Comment: MvxActionBarActivity is outdated and i wouldn't reccomend using it anymore. If you are missing any tutorials or samples please fill an issue here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples